# comparing $_get result to db stored value

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post, get

i have a multiple choice quiz which sends a possible answer via URL like this

```
<form method="post" action="test2score.php?q=<?php echo $quiz_id; ?>">
```

on the test2score.php page it reads and tries to compare the value like this

```
$ans = mysql_result(mysql_query('select c_answer from quiz where quiz_id = "'.$_GET['q'].'"'),0);
    if ($_POST['answer'] == $ans){
        echo "You got it right!";
    }else if ($_POST['answer'] <> $ans){
        echo "You got it wrong!";
    }
```

where c_answer is the correct answer stored in db, but even when i select the right answer and post it it still echoes "you got it wrong"

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your quiz has only one question

Comment: sql injection: `example.com/test2score.php?q=1" and "1=1` and why not hold users answers in a session, then you dont have to POST/pass anything

Comment: echo $_GET['q']; see what do you get?

Comment: As @LawrenceCherone says, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection!  If you don't know what that is, or how to avoid it, read about [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: maybe this is of importance, the radio button answer choice are generated like this foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
            echo "<input type='radio' name='answer'>".$value."</input><br />";
        }

Answer (score 0):

Your form `method="post"` is post and your receiving values in `$_GET['q']` Kindly correct either of the one
Or use

```
$_REQUEST['q']`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden field q and post that value to your action page and receive that value using

```
$_POST['q'] and use that in your query.
```

Thanks.

Comment: tried using the hidden field, still getting an echo "you got it wrong"

Comment: Now you have to check the ` $_POST['answer'] ` value. Is it coming from radio button or checkbox ? you should print this value and manually compare with the db value whether they are exactly same or not.

Comment: found the culprit, the echo $_POST['answer']; is not getting the right answer from radio post.. i am using this code to pull up the radio foreach ($row as $key => $value) { echo "<input type='radio' name='answer'>".$value."</input><br />"; }

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a $_GET request in the action of a form that is $_POST?  Since you aren't worried about your users seeing the value of `q` then why not just put a hidden input in the form with the results of `q`:

```
<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $quiz_id ?> name="q" />
```

Then in your query, check for `$_POST['q']`

Seems the saner, more logical way to achieve this

Comment: tried using the hidden field, still getting an echo "you got it wrong"

Answer (score 0):

instead of passing quiz id from form action pass it from hidden form field

like below
set form action to

```
action="test2score.php"
```

and take hidden form field as

```
<input type="hidden" name="q" value=<?php echo $quiz_id; ?> />
```

and get that value like below

```
$_POST['q'];
```

Comment: tried using the hidden field, still it's echoeing "you got it wrong"